# How to remove return list view from parent linearlayout?

Tags: java, android, view, android-linearlayout

I have MainActivity and ListClassFile .

The MainActivity have Linearlayout(name is recordContent) component from XML.(using findviewById to get).

In ListClassFile file, I call setListHandler will return ListView class.

Now, I have two button in the MainActivity. When I click A button.

It will call

```
private ListClassFile rdActivity = null;
private LinearLayout recordContent = null;
....
@Overrid
protected void onCreate(...){
...
  recordContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.recordContent);

    ...
    if( rdActivity == null )
        {
            rdActivity = new ListClassFile();
            recordContent.addView( rdActivity.setListHandler(MainActivity.this) ); 

           // rdActivity.setListHandler(MainActivity.this) it will return listview

        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The `listview` will show.

When I click B button.

I will call

```
   if( rdActivity != null )
          {
                rdActivity = null;
                recordContent.removeAllViews();
          }
```

It will remove successfully.

But I just want to remove `listview`. Not all views in recordContent.

How to appoint remove  `listview (rdActivity.setListHandler(MainActivity.this) )?`

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the returned listview to the instance variable, use that while removing.

```
private ListClassFile rdActivity = null;
private LinearLayout recordContent = null;
private ListView lv;
....
@Overrid
protected void onCreate(...){
...
  recordContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.recordContent);

    ...
    if( rdActivity == null )
        {
            rdActivity = new ListClassFile();
            lv = rdActivity.setListHandler(MainActivity.this);
            recordContent.addView(lv); 

           // rdActivity.setListHandler(MainActivity.this) it will return listview

        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In click B button

```
if( rdActivity != null )
{
rdActivity = null;
**recordContent.removeView(lv);**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of call

```
recordContent.removeAllViews();
```

Call:

```
recordContent.removeView(rdActivity);
```

Or you can get number of chields and remove last:

```
int num = recordContent.getChildCount();
recordContent.removeViewAt(num-1);
```

Comment: recordContent.removeView(rdActivity); will show error. Because call rdActivity.setListHandler(MainActivity.this) will return listview, not call rdActivity.  I have try to set ListView lv public in ListClassFile. I call recordContent.removeView(rdActivity.lv); will correct.  
thank you very much